# Show duplicate value in array only one but show all others

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, filter-var

can i showing only one value in foreach array having multiple same value, without grouping the array firstly in the query like this :

```
0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'questionname' => string 'question 01' (length=36)
      'answerspossible' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'answer' => string 'YES' (length=3)
      'answer2' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'questionname' => string 'question 01' (length=36)
      'answerspossible' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'answer' => string 'YES' (length=3)
      'answer2' => string 'test answer' (length=0)
```

Result i want in the view is to group by the questioname inside the foreach :

```
question 01 :
          - answer & answer 2 
          - answer & answer 2
```

My code is :

```
foreach ($Questions as $Key => $Question) {

        echo $question['questionname'];
        echo $Question['answer']." & ".$Question['answer2'];

}
```

thnx for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$justblank = ''; // just a blank variable we will use it later.
foreach ($Questions as $Key => $Question) {
        echo $question['questionname'];
        $questionanswers = $Question['answer']." & ".$Question['answer2'];
        if($justblank == $questionanswers){
            break;
        }else{
            echo $questionanswers;
        }
        $justblank .= $questionanswers;
}
```

Hi Mohammed, I hope this help you :).

Answer (score 0):

a blank var work

```
$justblank = -1; 
foreach ($Questions as $Key => $Question) {
   if($Question['id']!=$justblank){
    echo $Question['questionname'];
    $justblank=$Question['id'];

   }
     ....
}
```